# How to store multiple values in a single column in a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to be able to store/display information about different gym branches in the database. I have the following information about each branch.

1. Id
2. Name
3. RoomNumber
4. Capacity
5. Address

Each branch will have its unique address and each RoomNumber will have a different capacity and branch name. I have searched and tried different ways but I am unable to fix it. The below code shows what I have done.

The Branch Model that will store a record of each branch.

```
 public class Branch
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Display(Name = "Branch Name")]
     [StringLength(50)]
     public List<BranchName> BranchName { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public int RoomNumber { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Range(5, 30)]
     public int Capacity { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [StringLength(50)]
     public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

This is the BranchName model with RoomNumbers.

```
 public class BranchName
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public List<int> RoomNumbers { get; set; } 
 }
```

The below screen shot shows when run migration, BranchName model does not add the list of the rooms property.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: In this, I would suggest to go for MongoDB or similar document based database or you store `BranchName`' in separate table or store the Branch list as JSON string in MSSQL database

Comment: Please do not attempt to store multiple vales in a single column in a database. That violates [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and will cause you an unbelievable number of problems. If you are having trouble “add the list of the rooms property” then show us how you “run migration” and fix that.

Comment: Assuming this is Entity Framework, Entity Framework doesn't support direct storage of collections (migrations will ignore that). You'd need to have a separate RoomNumber entity and a relationship allowing you to have a collection of RoomNumbers (or Rooms) even if you only store a number in each of those entities. Alternatives include pre-processing i.e. writing the numbers to a string and reading them back into a list but it can get messy.

Comment: The setup for this is confusing. Why are you storing the branch details as a list? You'd be indicating that multiple branches could have the same room number, capacity, and address. Branch should likely be an object that stores data specific to the branch (name, address, etc.), and then you have a room object that stores data specific to the room (number, capacity, amenities, etc), and then you'd tie those together, likely in a third object, so you have the branch details as an object and the room details in some kind of collection.

Comment: I have noticed over the past year that Microsoft experts, when talking about NoSql database design, now talk about both "one-to-many" and "one-to-few" relationships. It would be useful if the OP could clarify which applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not breaking down the idea of a branch and rooms quite correctly. Based on your objects, you're indicating that multiple branches could have the same address since you store the branch names as a collection, but only one address. This means several branches would also have the same room information, which is also inaccurate. You also don't just want to store a collection of room numbers because then you have to do more work to get the details *about* that room.

Here's a better breakdown:

```
public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }
}
```

You have one object for the Branch, simply called Branch, which has all the details specific TO that branch. The same applies to the Room details. Inside the branch object you have a collection of Room objects to store the details about all the rooms. By adding a BranchId value to the room object you indicate that room and its details only apply to the branch at which it's actually located, and now Room can be expanded to include information that branch and anyone looking to use it would find relevant. Also makes it easy to quickly obtain all the related rooms when you get any given branch's details.

Comment: I am Using Entity Framework. In my Branch Table I don't see any rooms column (which links the two tables) after running the migration. I am only able to display information from the Branch not the Room table (when I use the include method).

Comment: You shouldn't see a Rooms column in the table for branch data. Did you establish that the BranchId property in Room is a foreign key to the Id column in the Branch table?

Comment: Thank you, Yes I have figured it out and fixed my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear. :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can't represent a collection as a single column. Your design which you are trying to establish, completely incompitable with relational database logic. It seems that it is suffice to have two entity which are `Room` and `Branch` in your case.

```
public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Branch Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
public class Room
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(5, 30)]
    public int Capacity { get; set; }

    public int BranchId { get; set; }

    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}
```

- Per `Branch` contains its `Name`, `Address`
- Per Room contains its `RoomNumber`, `Capacity` and `BrandId` which is assosicated with `Branchs` table

Comment: And an example of a forward-looking benefit to this approach is that if/when you get into scheduling the room all you need is an event table with the Event ID, Room ID and the start/stop dates/times.  No need to unpack multiple values and try to correlate them with the schedule.

Comment: @Rainman Would you please explain how my Branch model will look like. Thank you